# Eclipse Neon build errors despite successful build

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse to do the development for a project that involves Gazebo (a popular robotics simulator).  Gazebo provides a plugin system to allow external interaction with the simulator and a series of tutorials on how to write plugins.

Having followed the tutorials successfully, I tried migrating the code to Eclipse, using cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" [buildpath] to generate an eclipse rpoject, then importing it into my Eclipse workspace.

Everything generally went well, but I've run into a problem that is a bit odd:

When I compile my project, Eclipse comes back with "Member declaration not found" error referring to an SDFormat data type used in the signature to the ModelPush::Load function (see code snippets below). SDFormat, incidnetally is a robotics XML used for describing how a robot is put together.

Despite this error (which should result in nothing being built), the resulting shared library is built anyway.

I guess I can live with it, but I'd obviously like to resolve this issue, which appears to be internal to Eclipse / CDT...

---

TO CLARIFY:

I'm trying to determine why Eclipse gives me the error: "Member declaration not found" on the Load() function signature in `model_push.cc`.  The guilty party is the `sdf::ElementPtr _sdf` parameter.  Something's wrong with the SDFormat library or with the way that Eclipse / CDT looks at it.  This isn't an include issue.  And, even though Eclipse gives me the error, it still builds the .so file.  Running make from the command line also generates the file, but without any errors.

Again, I can live with it, but I'd rather not.  I just don't know where to start looking for a solution since this isn't a problem finding an include or the sdf library file.

---

Here's the class declaration (mode_push.hh):

```
#ifndef MODEL_PUSH_HH_
#define MODEL_PUSH_HH_

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sdf/sdf.hh>

namespace gazebo
{
class ModelPush : public ModelPlugin
{
    public:

        void Load (physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf);

        //Called by the world update start event
        void OnUpdate (const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/);

    //Pointer to the model
    private:
        physics::ModelPtr model;

    //Pointer to the update event connection
    private:
        event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
};
}

#endif /* MODEL_PUSH_HH_ */
```

---

Here's the implementation file (model_push.cc):

---

```
#include "model_push.hh"

namespace gazebo
{
void ModelPush::Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
//void ModelPush::Load (physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*sdf*/)
{
    //Store the pointer to the model
    this -> model = _parent;

    //Listen to the update event.  This event is broadcast every
    //simulation iteration.
    this -> updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
        boost::bind (&ModelPush::OnUpdate, this, _1));
}

//Called by the world update start event
void ModelPush::OnUpdate (const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
{
    //Apply a small linear velocity to the model.
    this -> model -> SetLinearVel (math::Vector3 (0.03, 0.0, 0.0));
}

//Register this plugin with the simulator
//GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(ModelPush)
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your exact question and don't you want to include exact error and codeline where it happens

Comment: Updated.  See clarification included just before code snippets.

Comment: oh, so you are struggling not with compilation but with Eclipse's code analyzer, it does not look well documented

Comment: Generally, issues like this are caused by a mismatch between the configuration in which Eclipse is indexing the code (which is faulty), and the configuration in which the code is being built (which is correct). CMake's CDT project generation isn't perfect, and CDT itself isn't perfect. You can usually track down the mismatch by looking at the headers of the affected library (SDFormat in this case), and fix it by manually configuring additional include paths or configuration macros in Project Properties.

Comment: If you post a small project that reproduces the issue (in can even contain just the two source files you quoted in your post, but, importantly, it also needs to contain a cmakefile, so I can replicate your setup by running `cmake -G` as you did), I'm happy to try and track it down.

Comment: I'll work on a sample to see if I can replicate the error...

In the mean time, I've learned if I create a plain C++ project, bring in the source, then chase down the dependencies, eventually the project builds ok and CDT doesn't give me problems with any of the code.  

I also tried an alternate approach described here:

[link] (http://johnnado.com/use-cmake-with-eclipse/)

Eclipse won't generate makefiles and the include / library path tabs under Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings get disabled, but I have C/C++ General / Paths and Symbols to compensate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with this exact problem. I've found a solution that works, but I still don't think is ideal. Instead of generating the eclipse project using cmake (or catkin_make) I'm generating it using the CDT project builder. Here's the process I'm using in Eclipse 2018-09.

Create a New C/C++ Project of type C++ Managed Build (A C++ Project build using the CDT's managed build system.)

Project name: ROSWorkspace
Location: /home/username/eclipse-workspace/ROSWorkspace
Project type: Makefile project / Empty Project
Toolchain: Linux GCC

Finish.

Right click on the project and select Properties.

C/C++ Build / Builder Stetings:
Uncheck "Use default build command"
Build command: catkin_make
Build directory: ${workspace_loc:/../catkin_ws}/

C/C++ General / Paths and Symbols / Includes tab
Add /usr/include/gazebo-8
Add /usr/include/sdformat-5.3

C/C++ General / Preprocessor Includes / Providers tab
CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings / Command to get compiler specs: ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"  -std=c++11

Click Ok, then from the drop down menu choose:
Project / C/C++ Index / Freshen all files

Ideally I'd make the time to dig in to figure out how to get the preprocessor to properly work with the generated project, but I just don't have the time right now. I hope this helps.